# Property so that $f(t)\equiv 0$ for all $t\geq T$ for some finite $T>0$?

Tags: reference-request, real-analysis, differential-equations, parabolic-pde

Let $f:[0, \infty)\to [0, \infty)$ be non-decreasing and satisfy for all $t>t_{0}$, $$f(t)+C\int_{t_{0}}^{t}f^{\gamma}(s)ds\leq \frac{1}{t-t_{0}}\int_{t_{0}}^{t}f(s)ds,$$ where $0<\gamma<1$ and $C>0$.

Of course, if $f$ is differentiable and the somewhat similar differential inequality $$f'+Cf^{\gamma}\leq 0$$ holds, we have that $f(t)\equiv 0$ for all $t\geq T$ for some finite $T>0$. which follows from comparing $f$ with the function $g(t)=a(T-t)^{1/(1-\gamma)}$ where $a=((1-\gamma)C)^{1/(1-\gamma)}$.

**My question**: Is it possible to show that that $f(t)\equiv 0$ for all $t\geq T$ for some finite $T>0$ which does not use differentiation of $f$, that is, only the inequality in the first display math holds?

The differential inequality is, for example, used in the paper **Bénilan, Philippe, and Michael G. Crandall, "The Continuous Dependence on $p$ of Solutions of $u_{t}— \Delta \varphi(u) = 0$" Indiana University Mathematics Journal 30.2 (1981): 161-177** to show finite extinction time of a solution $u(x, t)$ of a  non-linear parabolic PDE. There, $f$ is an integral over $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ of some power of $u$ and the differentiation is with respect to $t$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm somewhat confused: Why does the integral inequality imply the differential inequality? Besides, if $f$ is non-decreasing and eventually 0, then $f$ is constantly $0$ from the beginning.

Comment: I think the differential inequality follows simply by differentiation of the integral inequality, right? Nevertheless, it does not really matter since, I want to show this property for general $f$...

Comment: Well, differentiation does not preserve inequalities. Anyway, your integral inequality together with the monotonicity assumption implies that $f$ is $0$, as explained in my answer.

Comment: Assume $C=1$ and $f$ decreasing. Then $f(t)+tf^\gamma (t) \leq f(0)$ and so $f(t) \leq Ct^{-1\gamma}$. Since $1/\gamma>1$, $\int_0^\infty f <\infty$ and letting $t \to \infty$ in the original inequality, $\int_0^\infty f^\gamma=0$. Then $f=0$ identically, not only for large $t$. Is this coherent with what you have or I did some mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $f$ is non-decreasing, the integral inequality implies that $f$ is $0$.

**Proof.** The integral inequality implies, in particular, that the same inequality is satisfied for $C=0$, so
$$
  \int_{t_0}^t f(t) \, ds = (t-t_0)f(t) \le \int_{t_0}^t f(s) \, ds
$$
for all $t \ge t_0$. Now fix $t > t_0$. Then it follows that the non-increasing function $g: [t_0,t] \ni s \mapsto f(t) - f(s) \in [0,\infty)$ has integral $\le 0$ over the interval $[t_0,t]$, and thus this integral is actually $0$. So $g(s) = 0$ for all $s \in (t_0,t]$ and hence, $f(t) = f(s)$ for all $s \in (t_0,t]$. Since $t > t_0$ was arbitrary, it follows that $f$ is constant on $(t_0,\infty)$.

Using the integral inequality from the question again, but now with $C > 0$, one can readily check that the constant value of $f$ on $(t_0,\infty)$ is $0$. As $f$ is non-decreasing, we conclude that $f$ is constantly $0$ on $[0,\infty)$. $\square$

Comment: Thank your for your answer but I guess I made a mistake... I need this property if $f$ is actually **non-increasing**. Do you know if the answer is still 'yes'? Of course, I will nevertheless accept your answer.

Comment: @Shaq155: The non-increasing case seems to be more difficult. I don't know what happens in this case.