# Integral inequality implies $f(t)\equiv 0$ for all $t\geq T$ for some finite $T>0$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequalities, integration

Let $f:[0, \infty)\to [0, \infty)$ be **non-increasing** and satisfy for all $t>t_{0}$, $$f(t)+C\int_{t_{0}}^{t}f^{\gamma}(s)ds\leq \frac{1}{t-t_{0}}\int_{t_{0}}^{t}f(s)ds,$$ where $0<\gamma<1$ and $C>0$.

**My question**: Is it true that $f(t)\equiv 0$ for all $t\geq T$ for some finite $T>0$?

**Remark**: If $f$ is differentiable and the somewhat similar differential inequality $$f'+Cf^{\gamma}\leq 0$$ holds, we have that $f(t)\equiv 0$ for all $t\geq T$ for some finite $T>0$. This follows from comparing $f$ with the function $g(t)=a(T-t)^{1/(1-\gamma)}$ where $a=((1-\gamma)C)^{1/(1-\gamma)}$.

See also [Property so that $f(t)\equiv 0$ for all $t\geq T$ for some finite $T>0$?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/440661/property-so-that-ft-equiv-0-for-all-t-geq-t-for-some-finite-t0) for the case when $f$ is non-decreasing.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $f$ is nonnegative and nonincreasing, we have $f(t)\to L$ as $t\to\infty$ for some  $L\in[0,\infty)$. Then from your first display we get
$$L+C\int_{t_{0}}^\infty f^{\gamma}(s)\,ds\le L.$$
So, $f=0$ on $(t_0,\infty)$, as desired.

Comment: This implies that $f$ is zero on all of $[0, +\infty)$ since $t_{0}$ is arbitrary, right?

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/441956/integral-inequality-implies-ft-equiv-0-for-all-t-geq-t-for-some-finite-t#comment1140513_441959), what does "$t_0$ is arbitrary" mean?  Your question specified that an inequality held for *some* $t_0$; did you mean that it held for *all* $t_0$?

Comment: @Shaq155 : The answer to the question in your comment depends on what you meant by the ambiguous phrase "for all $t>t_0$". A usual interpretation of it would be, as noted by LSpice, as follows: "for some real $t_0\ge0$ and all $t\in(t_{0},\infty)$"; so, in this case $t_0$ is "fixed". If you instead meant "for all $t_0$ and $t$ in $[0,\infty)$ such that $t>t_0$" -- then, of course, it follows from my answer that $f=0$ on $(0,\infty)$ (but not necessarily on $[0,\infty)$).

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative proof that also works with the RHS has a constant.
Suppose
$$ f(t) + C \int_{t_0}^t f^\gamma \leq \frac{B}{t-t_0} \int_{t_0}^t f $$
Since $f$ is non-increasing and non-negative, it is bounded by $f(t_0)$. So we find
$$ C \int_{t_0}^t f^\gamma \leq \frac{B}{t-t_0} \int_{t_0}^t f^\gamma f^{1-\gamma} \leq \frac{B f^{1-\gamma}(t_0)}{t - t_0} \int_{t_0}^t f^\gamma $$
Evaluating at $t$ such that $B f^{1-\gamma}(t_0) < C(t-t_0)$ we see that $f$ must vanish identically on $[t_0,t]$, and hence on $[t_0,\infty)$.